# holes in background (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image

See this http://cl.ly/image/1R0L3H3B0x3I

I have a fixed background on my website which is 100% wide and when I scroll the page that background starts to look really weird (check image above). It should be solid background and at first it is, but when I start to scroll the page it gets those weird holes it in and they doesn't appear in the same places all the time.

This is CSS I used for that div:

```
.bg-style-5 {
    background-image: url("images/bg-6.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 1000px;
    margin-left: -1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

It fixes itself when I switch browser tabs, so I assume this is a Chrome bug. Has anyone experienced something like this? Maybe there is a solution to this problem?

**Solution**: I had added `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to one of the parent elements and it caused this weird behavior.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll have better responses to your questions if you can be more specific with code examples.  It is hard to diagnose problems with only your description of what is happening.

Comment: @SteveH. - heh, 'welcome' to a 2 year old SO user.

Comment: Not able to reproduce your problem, seems to work for me...but i would avoid the use of a 2.2Mb image size...il will have a look at CSS instead, to render the same...using div to render the boxes "Free" / "$23/month" etc...